# Why is there such an arrow in my xml in Android Studio? And how to make it disappear?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

**Code**

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="295"
    android:background="@drawable/shape_titlebar_background"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@color/color_white"
    android:textSize="@dimen/sp_12"/>
```

**Screenshot**

**The arrow in the red box**

[image]

**How to make it disappear?**

**Edit**

I used @BharaniK's answer .This was only useful in the current activity XML file .

When I create a new activity,It will not be useful in the new activity XML file.And I will reset it .

How to make it disappear in the whole project when I set it up only once?

Comment: Is this from your `xml` or a sign from your `IDE`, I think it is the second, some kind of formatting maybe

Answer (score 1):

The arrow mark that you see is the line separator indicated by IDE, as IDE soft-wrapped the lines. The reason why are you seeing for android:background attribute is because the length of that line is higher and it can't indent in the same way as it did for other attributes.

For a better understanding, play around with length of attribute values and text wrap settings in your IDE.

Comment: Do you know how to make it disappear?

Comment: @KeLiuyue Which IDE/Editor are you using. you should be able to do it by disabling text wrap. Usually, this is very common and developers just don't bother about it, as it does not change your underlying xml. This is just a decoration added by IDE to improve readability.

Comment: Android studio.

Comment: You can search the settings with `cmd + shift + A` or `ctrl + shift + A` and turn off `Soft wraps: use soft wraps in editor`

Comment: Thank you for you help.@RobCo

Comment: It was only useful in the current activity XML file .

Comment: Sorry to trouble you .

Answer (score 1):

Goto `View -> Active Editor` and Unmark `Use Soft Wraps`